# Combining two matrices using ismember condition in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of size 1x10575 and another matrix `B` of size 13462x30974. All values of `A` are members of `B`. I would like to obtain a new matrix `C` of size 13462x10575 with the following condition.

If the value of `B` is a member of `A`, then return all values in the respective column of `B`. If `A` is not a member of `B` then do not respect this column anymore.

This would be an example of how the matrices could look like:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 11 12 13 14 15 16; 21 22 23 24 25 26];
B = [1 2 5 6];
```

The output should look like:

```
C = [1 2 5 6; 11 12 14 15; 21 22 24 25];
```

I tried the following code, yet it returns the output `C` in the wrong format (1x417281728).

```
[isMatch, index] = ismember(B(1, :), A);
C = nan(size(B, 1), numel(A));
C(:, index(isMatch)) = B(:, isMatch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically want to do is the following: "For each element in the array A, check whether this element exists in B, and then return the entire column." So your guess with `ismember` was completely correct, as you want to check whether A is a member of B. For your example, the result would be:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, you have to collapse all these indices into a single array, which says that there is at least one member which has a binary of 1. This you can do using the `any` command, which basically checks that there exists at least one TRUE in the considered dimension. So ultimately you end up with:

```
C = A(:,any(ismember(A,B),1))
```

[Note that in your example you have changed A and B, so in the code I posted it is also changed].

Comment: Could you link or include some relevant documentation for your command?